# spring-boot camel case nested property as environment variable

Tags: java, spring-boot, environment-variables

I have a spring boot application and want to set, though environment variables, in a class annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties` a second level nested property which is camel case. Here is an example of the class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SpringApp.Props.class)
@RestController
public class SpringApp {

  private Props props;

  @ConfigurationProperties("app")
  public static class Props {
    private String prop;
    private Props nestedProps;

    public String getProp() {
      return prop;
    }

    public void setProp(String prop) {
      this.prop = prop;
    }

    public Props getNestedProps() {
      return nestedProps;
    }

    public void setNestedProps(Props nestedProps) {
      this.nestedProps = nestedProps;
    }

  }

  @Autowired
  public void setProps(Props props) {
    this.props = props;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringApp.class, args);
  }

  @RequestMapping("/")
  Props getProps() {
    return props;
  }

}
```

when I try to run the application with following environment variables:

```
APP_PROP=val1
APP_NESTED_PROPS_PROP=val2
APP_NESTED_PROPS_NESTED_PROPS_PROP=val3
```

I'm getting following response from the service:

```
{
  "prop": "val1",
  "nestedProps": {
    "prop": "val2",
    "nestedProps": null
  }
}
```

Is this the expected behavior? I was expecting something like this:

```
{
  "prop": "val1",
  "nestedProps": {
    "prop": "val2",
    "nestedProps": {
      "prop": "val3",
      "nestedProps": null
    }
  }
}
```

When I am setting the properties through application parameters (eg: `--app.prop=val1 --app.nestedProps.prop=val2 --app.nestedProps.nestedProps.prop=val3`), I'm getting expected response.

Is there any workaround using environment variables and without modifying the code to get the expected behavior?

Note: I did some debugging and seems the problem is originated in `org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedNames` not generating candidates for this cases. Here is a test I did to demonstrate it (it fails):

```
@Test
public void shouldGenerateRelaxedNameForCamelCaseNestedPropertyFromEnvironmentVariableName() {
  assertThat(new RelaxedNames("NESTED_NESTED_PROPS_PROP"), hasItem("nested.nestedProps.prop"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try with the NESTED_NESTEDPROPS_PROP, bcs 'nestedProps' is one property

> The _ delimiter must not be used within a property name. i.e.
>   database-platform must be written as DATABASEPLATFORM and not
>   DATABASE_PLATFORM.

source: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Relaxed-Binding-2.0