# Custom property name mapper in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'd like to improve on the relaxed property binding in spring boot, so I can bind dotted and underscored properties to camelCased Java property names in @ConfigurationProperties beans.

e.g.:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("foo.bar")
public class FooProperties {
    private String helloThere;

    // getters & setters
}
```

I'd like to be able to map to the camelCase property with these property names:

```
foo.bar.hello.there
FOO_BAR_HELLO_THERE
```

What classes do I need to implement and inject into Spring Boot to make this work?

Comment: I dont think it is possible. Also check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729516/spring-boot-camel-case-nested-property-as-environment-variable